# Communicate with iframe (same domain) using Angular 4/5

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe

I am working on an application in which I need to display some components inside an `<iframe>`, so the `<iframe>` has the same origin.

I need to pass some values to this `<iframe>` (like logged in user information) from the parent component and the `<iframe>` can modify these values.

I know we can use [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to communicate with `<iframe>` that has a different origin and I can specify current origin to limit the exchange to only one origin. Is there a way apart from `window.postMessage` to communicate with an `<iframe>` that has the same origin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Session Storage** is a perfect way to communicate between iframes that belong to the same domain. [Official docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

You can also bind to storage change events.

In pure JS you can just do this ([JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Andrea/tggwg3oL/1/))

```
/* [Parent window] */
const writeToSessionEverySecond = function() {
    var value = 10;
    setInterval(function(){ 
      value++;
      sessionStorage.setItem('my_key', value);
    }, 1000);
}

writeToSessionEverySecond();


/* [Child window] Listen storage change events */
window.addEventListener('storage', function() {
    const valueFromSession = sessionStorage.getItem('my_key');
    console.log('VALUE ' + valueFromSession)
}, false);
```

**NOTE:** In order to really fire an event, the content of the session must change. If you set the same value the event wont fire.

If you are using RxJs you can use observables to build simple yet powerful logic on storage events streams, i.e,

```
Rx.Observable.fromEvent(window, 'storage').
              .<rx operators to do your magic>()
              .subscribe(..);
```

-Andrea

Comment: Yeah, I know that is an option, but was wondering if there is a way that I can communicate with the parent frame without having to listen to the `message` event (using the entire window.postMessage setup)

Comment: SessionStorage looks like a good option.Is there no way or no angular way of communication with the `iframe`?

Comment: Since my application is one big angular app which is divided into modules, I am able to inject a service into the components that I displayed in the `iframe` (used child routes for the display). I am accepting this answer even though I did not use it because it also presents a way of achieving what I want.