# angular 6 component function doesnt work from HostListener from iframe

Tags: iframe, window, message, angular6

i have an angular 6 application, and a different web application inside in an iframe.
when i receive  message from the iframe with the postmessage function, i do get to
the onMessage function, and then i do get to the openOffNet - but then the popup doesnt work.
it doesnt work when i activate the popup from a button.
anyone have any idea why it does not work?

thank you

```
 import {HostListener, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import {NgbModal, NgbActiveModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
    import {NgbdModalContentComponent} from '../ngbd-modal-content/ngbd-modal-content.component';
    import {ModalAddDeviceComponent} from '../popupBoxes/modal-add-device/modal-add-device.component';
    import {ModalAddOffnetComponent} from '../popupBoxes/modal-add-offnet/modal-add-offnet.component';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-top-bar',
      templateUrl: './top-bar.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./top-bar.component.css']
    })
    export class TopBarComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) { 
        (<any>window).onMessage= this.onMessage.bind(this);
      }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

       @HostListener('window:message', ['$event'])
      onMessage(e) {
        console.log('HostListener');
        if(e.data.function == 'subnetworkClicked'){

        }
        else{
          console.log("open popUp");
          this.openOffNet();
        }



      }




      openOffNet () : void {
        const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ModalAddOffnetComponent);

      }
    }
```

Comment: This might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50093664/communicate-with-iframe-same-domain-using-angular-4-5

Answer (score 1):

Try 'document:message' instead of 'window:message'